# AngularJS directive with isolated scope - default attributes values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with isolated scope. In the scope there is a property - passed as a string ('@').

This attribute is optional - I want to set some default value to the property if no value is passed in the directive attributes. So I've written the following line of code:

```
scope.someProperty = scope.someProperty || "New Value";
```

But this does not work as I expected... the `scope.someProperty` remains empty.

I explored around a bit and understand that one way binding to isolated scope property (@) means that the parent value can be read but not write into. what I wish to do is to set the local directive property value and not to change the parent.

How can I do it?

Please see an example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcQwGKv3WDbjJBiqTmhO?p=preview).

Comment: Try scope.someProperty = "New Value"; and override it whenever necessary. Since angular is two way binding scope.someProperty = scope.someProperty || "New Value"; will bring unnecessary confusions.

Comment: Isolate scope prevents unnecessary confusions. Angular is not always two-way data binding – @ is for one way binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/95nQTSwmSp3I1dEJ63ET?p=preview)

`scope.someProperty = scope.someProperty || "New Value";`

This assignment will set the `someProperty` value to `New Value`. But after the initial digest cycle because of `scope: {someProperty: '@'}` statement, angular updates the `someProperty` value to the corresponding attribute value which is empty.

Try this to provide the default value.

```
attrs.$observe('someProperty', function (nv, ov) {
  if (!nv) {
    scope.someProperty = "New Value";
  }
})
```

Comment: This sounds very reasonable... do you have any solution for me? how can I give default values to optional attributes?

Comment: @user2717436, Please check the updated answer and plnkr.

Comment: Is this solution going to have a significant impact on the performance?

Comment: Do you have any documentation that confirm it? something I can show my managers for evidence?

Comment: I don't have any documentation to confirm it.

Comment: So... may I be rude enough to ask - how do you know it? as far as I know watches and observers are recommended to be avoid, since they impact performance. BTW - thank you so far for your quick and accurate answers!

Comment: With the experience of building a RADD(www.wavemakeronline.com) tool using angular js I said that.

Comment: Ho it looks great! now I feel safer... Thanks!